# lwc getFieldValue from a custom external object

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, schema, lwc-wire-adapter

I am creating a LWC that handles data from an external object. I have access to the recordId through `@api recordId;`, but I need to get the `externalId` from this object as well.

Currently, I have call to an APEX class that simply returns the `ExternalId`  of that record.

```
public with sharing class EnterpriseCaseHandler {
    @AuraEnabled
     public static String getCaseRecordID(ID currentRecordId){
        return [SELECT ExternalId FROM EntCase__x WHERE id= :currentRecordId LIMIT 1].ExternalId; 
    }
}
```

While this works, I am wondering if there is a way to eliminate this call and get the field value of `ExternalId` directly from the record.

I am trying to follow this documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_value

Is there support for external objects? I may have the schema incorrect, just not sure how to determine what it should be.

Here is my code:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from "lwc";
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import EXTERNAL_ID from "@salesforce/schema/EntCase__x.ExternalId"; // External Object

const fieldValues = [EXTERNAL_ID];

export default class ChatterData extends LightningElement {

  /**
   * Get the field values for this external case record
   */
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fieldValues })
  entCase;

  /**
   * Get the externalId for this case record
   */
  get externalId() {
    return getFieldValue(this.entCase.data, EXTERNAL_ID);
  }

  renderedCallback() {
    let external = getFieldValue(this.entCase.data, EXTERNAL_ID);
    console.log(external) // returns {}
    console.log(this.entCase.data) // returns {} 
    console.log(this.entCase) // returns {}
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't have external objects in my org to test against, but I wouldn't be too optimistic about being able to use the UI API here (see docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm).  The syntax mostly looks all right, *except* it does occur to me that `renderedCallback()` might execute before your wired record is populated.  What happens if you put `<p>{externalId}</p>` somewhere in the template?  If you don't see it then, I would go back to Apex.

Comment: @MatthewSouther - Bummer, I tried that as well using the getter and it didn't display. I added an error callback to my `@wire` and got a response of `aura_prod.map.js:41912 {"ok":false,"status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error","body":{"errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD","message":"Entity name for the provided record didn't match required field EntCase__c.ExternalId","stack":"Error: Entity name for the provided record didn't match required field EntCase__c.ExternalId\n `. Looks like it is trying to use `EntCase__c` vs `EntCase__x`. Doesn't appear to support external objects from what I can tell

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that even though we import the field from the external object path ***.../externalObject__x.customfield__c*** the objectApiName of the imported field will have the custom object suffix ( **__c** ) instead of the external object suffix( **__x** ).

I've managed this to work by manually defining the structure of the field and making sure the objectApiName has an external suffix instead of a custom one.

```
   //Defined outside the class
    const FIELDS = [
      {
        fieldApiName: 'myExternalField__c',
        objectApiName:'myExternalObject__x'
      }
    ]; 


    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: FIELDS})
    entCase;
```

Hope this works!